# Angular2 Observable Callback

Tags: angular, observable

Im trying to implement a simple callback once an observable has finished, here is my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.propertyService
    .getProperties()
    .subscribe(
        (data: ContentPropertyModel[]) => this.properties = data
    );
    this.status = 'active';
}
```

However the status is changed before the observable runs. Any ideas on how i can changes the this.status after the observable runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscribe takes in three arguments(OnNext function, Error Function, Completed Function).

If you want to run your code to run after each item is received then code in the first function argument. If you want to run after the completion of the stream then code in the last function argument.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.propertyService
    .getProperties()
    .subscribe(
        (data: ContentPropertyModel[]) => {
            this.properties = data
        },
        (err) => console.log(err),
        () => this.status = 'active'
    );
}
```

Refer this link http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html.

Also onError() and Completed() function wont work for DOM events.

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer

Answer (score 5):

Move `this.status` to your subscribe handler:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.propertyService
    .getProperties()
    .subscribe(
        (data: ContentPropertyModel[]) => {
            this.properties = data
            this.status = 'active';
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as pointed out in another answer, you must set `status` within the `subscribe` handler. However, this also means that `status` is not set at all until the observable emits its first item. I'd suggest as an alternative making `status` an observable itself, which you can accomplish with something like

```
this.status$ = this.propertyService.getProperties()
  .startWith(false)
  .map(b => b ? 'active' : 'waiting');
```

Now in your template to display status

```
STATUS IS {{status$ | async}}
```

And the display will be `waiting` until the observable first fires.

If you should need to access the current value of `status` in an event handler, you can do so with

```
logStatus() {
  this.status$.take(1).subscribe(s => console.log("status is", s);
}
```

If you treat `properties` in the same way, as an observable,

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.properties$ = this.propertyService.getProperties();
  this.status$ = this.properties$.startWith(false).map(b => b ? 'active' : 'waiting');
}
```

then you can avoid altogether subscriptions in your `ngOnInit` which will need to be remembered and then torn down in `ngOnDestroy`.